# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Tags: fatal-error

I'm trying to use `mysqli_*` statements because my WAMP server says `mysql_*` statements are deprecated but I'm facing some errors. Please have a look. Maybe I've made some silly mistakes.

The `select` query runs fine but when binding the parameters for the `update` query, it triggers an error.

```
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db_intranet');

$time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$caltime=strtotime($time)-1800;
$currTime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$caltime);

$query = $mysql->query('select username,srvid from temp_day_test where start_time<"'.$currTime.'" && end_time="0000-00-00 00:00:00" && status="yes"');


while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{

$data[]=$row;




if(isset($row['srvid']) && $row['srvid']!="" && $row['username']!=''){
$srvid = $row['srvid'];
$username = $row['username'];
$testid = 44;

$query = 'UPDATE rm_users SET srvid =? WHERE username =? && srvid=?';
$stmt = $mysql->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->bind_param('isi',$srvid,$username,$testid);

//$update = $mysql->query('UPDATE rm_users SET srvid = '.$srvid.' WHERE username = "'.$username.'" && srvid=44');

if($result->execute())


{
    echo 'ok';
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
}

}
```

Comment: I don't believe `&&` is valid SQL syntax...

Comment: If I had to guess, your query contains the invalid `&&` characters so your `prepare` statement is failing. Try adding `print_r($stmt)` after your `$stmt = $mysql->prepare($query);` line. I'm guessing that it will echo `0` or `false` meaning the statement errored out.

Comment: I'm surprised you ever get into the while loop. What's the output if you do `print_r($query->fetch_assoc());` just before the while loop?

Comment: thanku everybody 4 ur favorable rply. actually what did after failing of this script is deleted evrything and used mysql on desktop at my office because i've to cmplete the project anyhow.. and it was stopping to do so....